# Accessing winedbg process to see what happened

Tags: java, wine

I'm a java developer. Wine (version 1.2) was set up by IT. I have a multithreaded java process running on a linux box that uses wine to call out to windows processes. Occasionally my java process will hang. I don't see any errors or indication in my logging of anything wrong, but I do see a winedbg process:

```
 8673 ?        SN     0:00 winedbg --auto 244 684
```

I also see these other wine processes:

```
 5873 ?        SNs   94:31 ~/apps/wine-1.2/bin/wineserver
 5879 ?        SNl    0:00 C:\windows\system32\services.exe
 5881 ?        SNl    0:00 C:\windows\system32\winedevice.exe MountMgr
 6507 ?        SNl    0:03 C:\windows\system32\rpcss.exe
23679 ?        SNs    0:00 C:\windows\system32\explorer.exe /desktop
```

I've done a bit of googling and winehq has some documentation on using the debugger but I'm not seeing what I would apply to my situation.

How can I see what wine got hung up on?

Comment: That's perverse - why not just run Java in windows?

Comment: Thank you for your constructive comment. I'm bored so I'll respond to it. The requirements of the application demanded a lot of horsepower, so the box was purchased and either because of money or box requirements the box runs linux (the IT dept. made all these decisions I just do the best I can with what they give me). Ideally I wouldn't have to call windows processes but either a linux version of what I needed didn't exist or it wasn't good enough. But mainly I just like adding extra layers of buggy software between layers of my application so then I'll have an excuse to post something.